# 503 “Service Unavailable” error for all apps after installing .NET Core 2.2 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8.5, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm developing an angular 7 application with ASP.NET CORE 2.2 and when I deploy it in IIS 8.5 which is a Windows Server 2012 R2, all the web applications host in IIS gives **503 Service Unavailable** error and error goes away when I uninstall **.NET Core 2.2 Runtime & Hosting Bundle**

When I check the event view it shows me the following error:

```
A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '<ProcessId>' serving application pool '<ApplicationPoolName>' reported a listener channel failure.
```

Tried online and it was not success anyone has any solution?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/ did you have VC runtime installed as required?

Comment: Yes. It is done.

Comment: Check Windows event log and there should be relevant entries.

Comment: Event loggers says the above mentioned error.

Comment: Yes, please check your event viewer. Please also read this blog http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/How-to-Publish-ASPNET-Core-2.aspx

Comment: @Oshadha I know this is an older issue, but were you able to run your .net core app just by executing the API's  exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me more than one day to find a solution for this. Before you install **ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle (latest versions)**, you need to ensure you have installed [**Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable.**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145) in the system.

Installation(ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle) doesn't say anything if Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable is missing.

This helped to fixed the issue that I had. Hope this will help you.